# Stack test output garbled on MINGW64

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, mingw-w64

I'm running GHC using Stack on Windows 10, and using Git Bash (MINGW64) for much of my daily workflow. That includes using GHC and GHCi, which generally works fine.

However, when I run `stack test` from MINGW64, the output is garbled by ANSI color codes:

```
$ stack test
UC-0.1.0.0: test (suite: UC-test)

[?25lSorting Group 1:

[2K[1F  prop1: [[92mOK, passed 100 tests[0m]

[2K[1F  prop2: [[92mOK, passed 100 tests[0m]

         Properties  Total
 Passed  [92m2[0m           [92m2[0m
 Failed  0           0
 Total   [92m2[0m           [92m2[0m
[?25h
```

Strangely, if I run `stack test` from the normal Windows console (`cmd`), it displays correctly:

[image: Correctly coloured test output in cmd]

I'd like to stick with my (Git) Bash console instead of having to use two separate console windows, so:

- Is it possible to get the colours to render correctly for `stack test` in MINGW64?
- Alternatively, can I turn off ANSI colouring for `stack test`, so that, at least, it's easier to read the output?

I've also tried to run variations of `stack --color never test`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments can be passed to the test executable like this:

```
stack test --test-arguments "--plain"
```

`--plain` is the option to remove colors in test-framework, while `--color never` is from tasty.

Comment: It doesn't look like that's the case... When I copy that into my bash and run it, I get "Could not understand these extra arguments: never"

Comment: `--color never` is an option in tasty. Are you using another test framework?

Comment: test-framework has `--plain` instead. And in general you can try ask `--help` to the test executable.

Comment: Thank you, `--plain` does remove the colouring. I did try `--help`, but that one escaped me.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, although it's the next-best answer I had hoped for...

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this same issue on Windows 10, Git 2.17.0, with MINGW64 as the Git Bash shell.  Colors are fine until I run "php artisan tinker", after which colors cease and suddenly all output is garbled with the ANSI color codes.

My solution turned out to be (it surprised me that it worked):  run Bash inside the Git Bash shell.

Before:

```
$ php artisan tinker
?[34mPsy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.1.11 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman?[39m
>>> exit
?[37;41mExit:  Goodbye.?[39;49m
$
```

After:

```
$ bash
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.1.11 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.
$
```

It's really a work-around, but it works. Maybe this is a clue to the actual underlying issue. Terminal type did not seem to matter (xterm, xterm-256, etc.) were all tried with little difference.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue, but thanks for sharing :)