# Is there a way to get GHC error messages properly formatted on powershell terminal when built with stack?

Tags: windows, powershell, haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

Building with ghc prints beautifully formatted error messages on powershell (as in other terminals):

```
PS > ghc .\src\XXX.hs -package ghc -package ghc-paths -package filepath

[1 of 1] Compiling XXX           ( src\XXX.hs, src\XXX.o )

src\XXX.hs:340:9: error:
    parse error on input `<-'
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?
    |
340 |   blah  <- blah blah blah
    |         ^^
```

But when building through stack, something goes wrong:

```
PS > stack build
XXX-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library for XXX-0.1.0.0..
Building library for XXX-0.1.0.0..
[2 of 3] Compiling XXX ( src\XXX.hs, .stack-work\dist\5c8418a7\build\XXX.o )

←[;1msrc\XXX.hs:340:9: ←[;1m←[31merror:←[0m←[0m←[;1m←[0m←[0m←[;1m
    parse error on input `<-'
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?←[0m←[0m
←[;1m←[34m    |←[0m←[0m
←[;1m←[34m340 |←[0m←[0m   blah ←[;1m←[31m<-←[0m←[0m blah blah blah
←[;1m←[34m    |←[0m←[0m←[;1m←[31m         ^^←[0m←[0m
←[0m←[0m←[0m
```

Is this a bug in stack, or is there a setting to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like ANSI ESCape sequences that aren't interpreted correctly

Comment: thanks! yes... and stack build --color never turns them off... but can it be fixed?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45608617/126014

Answer (score 3):

Turning off "use legacy console" in the cmd options does the trick!

Seems to be due to ansi color escape sequences - thanks @LotPings

Also:
    stack build --color never

gives monochrome but otherwise correctly formatted error messages.